# How to identify the level of tooth a paper has?

Tags: paper, colored-pencils

I have 145 gsm Cartridge paper in my house. I want to know whether it is great for colored pencil drawing or not.

I am told that toothed paper is great for colored pencils. So, I want to know how to find what level of tooth the paper has.

What would be the way to find out whether it is the best, good, or worst for it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This paper is fine for colored pencils. But its weight is maybe a bit low, so do not erase too much. Also you will probably have the grain still apparent even after several layers. But it is not necessarily a drawback, if it is the finish you want for your drawings.

To test your paper you can try to color little surfaces with different pressures, thus you will find the optimal pressure for your type of paper and colored pencils. Also you can try to layer different colors, in order to see after how many layers the paper starts to saturate.

Comment: How do you know it is fine for colored pencil?  Does gsm indicate the tooth level?

Comment: No it does not indicate the tooth level, but I have one or two times used this kind of paper, but it also depends of your colored pencils, if they are more or less creamy than mine you maybe won't have the same result.

Comment: When you say "paper starts to saturate" , what do you mean?

Comment: The paper has a saturation at which it will not be able to take any more color.